# Browsers are not responding to Server-Sent Events until server closes connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

On my Express/Node server, I set the content type to `text/event-stream`:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'
});
```

Then, as a series of callbacks fire, I write data messages to the stream and follow it with two new lines:

```
res.write('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n\n');
```

If I add logging on the server side or if I just hit the URL with `curl`, I can see that data messages are being written over a few seconds.

However, when I try to use these data messages in a web page, nothing happens. (I'm testing on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all on a Mac.) Here's what the Web page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Server-Sent Events Test</h1>

  <script>
    var source = new EventSource('/library/search?q=medicine&async');
    source.onmessage = function(e) {
      document.body.innerHTML += JSON.parse(e.data).name + '<br>';
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I add a final callback on the server side that closes the connection (using `res.end()`) then the browsers respond to the data messages all at once, and only once `res.end()` has happened. Which would seem to defeat the purpose of using Server-Sent Events.

What do I need to change (short of giving up and switching to XHR polling) to have the browsers respond to the Server-Sent Events as they arrive (which would seem to be exactly the purpose and use case for Server-Sent Events)?

(Test page demonstrating the problem was available but now that this problem has been resolved, I've removed it.)

Comment: When I `curl` the url being used on that test page, it comes back all at once.  What were you doing to see it show up in chunks?

Comment: @AaronDufour I may have been curling at a time when the services it depends on were busy. For now, I've added an artificial exponential backoff between callbacks so you should see the behavior I describe more clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have some middleware that is doing compression; and in doing this, it is buffering until you complete the response.  You can see this with curl:

First, bare GET:

```
curl <url>
```

Next, add an `Accept-Encoding` header (similar to what your browser is using):

```
curl <url>  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' --compressed
```

Note that `--compressed` just tells `curl` to decompress it for you.

You'll notice that you see the expected behavior on the first one, but not the second.  This makes it clear that it is related to the compression.  I suggest turning off compression for that route, or finding a smarter middleware that knows how to compress each frame.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the compression middleware and I see that their documentation even tells you what you have to do to get it to work with SSE (which is to add a call to `res.flush()` after `res.write()`). Brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me in Chrome. Here's my test code:

sse.js:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/sse.htm');
});
app.get('/events', function(req, res) {
  var counter = 0;
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream' });
  setInterval(function() {
    res.write('data: ' + JSON.stringify({name: 'foo' + (counter++) }) + '\n\n');
  }, 1000);
  res.write('data: ' + JSON.stringify({name: 'foo' + (counter++) }) + '\n\n');
});

app.listen(8000);
```

sse.htm:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Server-Sent Events Test</h1>

  <script>
    var source = new EventSource('/events');
    source.onmessage = function(e) {
      document.body.innerHTML += JSON.parse(e.data).name + '<br />';
    };
    source.onerror = function(e) {
      source.close();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this produces the following output:

```
foo0
// one second later
foo1
// two seconds later
foo2
// three seconds later
foo3
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me too, so clearly there's something else going on in my code that's messing stuff up.

Comment: Sorry I'm late but how are you supposed to serve this? If I run using node on localhost it works, if I run it on a remote server without HTTPS it does not